# filtrar lista em um Django admin foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Tenho duas dúvidas, ambas relacionadas ao formulário gerado automaticamente pelo admin do django. Se eu criar uma tela administrativa sei resolver estes problemas, mas trabalhando diretamente com o admin estou sofrendo um pouco, até mesmo porque acredito que o admin nem deva ser editado desta maneira, mas infelizmente não será possível migrar a curto prazo as telas administrativas para um template personalizado e fora do admin. Apresentado o contexto, eis minhas dúvidas:

1 - tenho um model com dois campos do tipo foreignkey apontando para model Empresa.

```
class Norma(models.Model):
    fornecedor = models.ForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        verbose_name="Fornecedor",   
        related_name="fornecedor+"
     )
     contato = models.ForeignKey(Contatos)
     numero = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Norma")
     descricao = models.CharField(verbose_name="Descrição")
     cliente = models.ForeignKey(
         Empresa,
         verbose_name="Cliente",
         related_name="cliente+"
     )
```

É possível, no formulário criado pelo admin, que na hora de inserir o fornecedor no campo fornecedor, apareçam somente as empresas que receberam o tipo "fornecedor"? E no cliente a mesma coisa, só que para Empresas marcadas com o tipo "clientes"?

```
class Empresa(models.Model):
    razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    apelido = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    tipo = models.ManyToManyField(Tipo)

class Tipo(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
```

2 - trazer os contatos somente da empresa do fornecedor selecionado.

```
class Contato(models.Model):
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, verbose_name="Empresa")
    nome_contato = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Nome do Contato")
```

Confesso que fiz isso de um jeito que não ficou bonito, pois eu editei o templat padrão do admin e fiz um bind evento on change no field do fornecedor  a uma callback que faz um ajax e traz a lista de contatos só para aquele fornecedor

```
$('body').on('change', '#id_fornecedor', function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.post('/empresas/contatos_fornecedor/', {id: id})
    .then(function(data){
            var contatos = JSON.parse(data);

            var options =  contatos.reduce(function(html, contato){
                return html+= "<option    value='"+contato.pk+"'>"+contato.fields.nome_contato+"</option>"
            }, "<option value=''>Selecione</option>");

        console.log(options);

        $('#id_contato').html(options);
    });
})
```

funciona perfeitamente, mas queria saber se não existe um jeito aonde eu não precise alterar o template, resolver isso no backend, alterando o admin.py por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a primeira parte você consiga resolver customizando o método `formfield_for_foreignkey` das classes de administração. Algo do tipo:

```
class NormaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "fornecedor":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Empresa.objects.filter(tipo__in='fornecedor')
        elif db_field.name == "cliente":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Empresa.objects.filter(tipo__in='cliente')
        return super(NormaAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(CleanerAdmin, Cleaner)
```

Quanto à segunda parte acho que não vai ter uma saída puramente de backend, com alguma modificação no admin.py não...

Comment: Muito obrigado! Aqui consegui realmente resolver a primeira parte. As únicas modificações que precisei fazer foi no filter(), do jeito que você postou o meu não funcionou, acho que poque em tipo, eu tenho outro foreign key que vai buscar tipo também, resumindo ficou assim:

Empresa.objects.filter(tipo__tipo__contains='Fornecedor')
Empresa.objects.filter(tipo__tipo__contains='Cliente')

E o meu admin.site.register só funciounou quando inverti os parâmetros, passei primeiro o model e depois o model admin:

admin.site.register(Normas, NormasAdmin)

Amigo, muito obrigado, me ajudou muito

Comment: Beleza!
Foi mal pelos pontos falhos da resposta, tava sem python e django pra testar.

Answer (score 0):

Ronaldo,

Acredito que a biblioteca [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) pode te ajudar. Eu ja utilizei esta lib em um projeto e funcionou bem. Inclusive o exemplo abaixo (extraido do README da mesma), exemplifica bem o seu caso, no meu ponto de vista. Veja:

Dado os seguinte modelos:

```
class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Country(models.Model):
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Location(models.Model):
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Uma vez selecionando um continente, caso você queira que apenas os países deste continente estejam disponiveis para seleção, você pode usar `ChainedForeignKey` no modelo `Location`

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

    class Location(models.Model)
        continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
        country = ChainedForeignKey(
            Country,
            chained_field="continent",
            chained_model_field="continent",
            show_all=False,
            auto_choose=True,
            sort=True)
        area = ForeignKey(Area)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Espero ter ajudado, e qualquer duvida estou a disposição!